# Manipulating objects in an array

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and been struggling to combine objects in the same array.
Here is what I have:

```
var testList = [{
  'taskList1': 'task1 for taskList1',
},
{
  'taskList1': 'task2 for taskList1',
},
{ 
  'taskList2': 'task1 for taskList2'
},
{
  'taskList2': 'task2 for taskList2'
}]
```

The array below is what I really want to get from above:

```
var testList = [{
  'taskList1': 'task1 for taskList1',
  'taskList2': 'task1 for taskList2'
},
{
  'taskList1': 'task2 for taskList1',
  'taskList2': 'task2 for taskList2'
}]
```

Could anyone please help me to transform my current array into the one above?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you tried something by far?

Comment: if you want to get there from here, you're probably doing it wrong.   Your current data model appears to be inside out.  It would be more usual to have your data grouped by task, and then have an array of tasks inside that.

Comment: I'd also note that trying to get there from here is not simple because in each iteration you don't know a priori which entry in the array the task has to be added to, but if your data structure was inverted it would be completely trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is quite inefficient in this case. I'd suggest to make it better by having the same array of objects, but each object should contain `itemName` and `belongsTo` as a reference to any collection (in your case - a `taskList`) you may pass there.

Here's a solution to your problem with a more flexible data structure on Codepen - https://codepen.io/Inlesco/pen/dReYgd

I've also added the restructured array of tasks below as an example that's used in the Codepen above.

```
var testList = [{
  item: 'task1',
  belongsTo: 'taskList1'
},
{
  item: 'task2',
  belongsTo: 'taskList1'
},
{ 
  item: 'task1',
  belongsTo: 'taskList2'
},
{
  item: 'task2',
  belongsTo: 'taskList2'
}]
```

There are many ways to approach this problem. I've just added probably the simplest one.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: please put code in your answer - not on third party sites

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for statement to regroup objects with the same taskList ID in one object.
And of course your need to use the right conditions for that.
But the best way is as @Denialos said, to modify your data structure.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It looks like the data structure that I have is wrong. I will try to change it to the way @Denialos suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comments above to the question, your desired data structure appears to be inverted, or "inside out".    Given a list of items, and a set of tasks for each item, I would expect the outer element to be the list, and the inner element to be the set of tasks.

Given that, given your (current) input data I would use:

```
function restructure(taskList) {
    var result = {};

    for (var i = 0, n = taskList.length; i < n; ++i) {

        // read current item
        var item = taskList[i];
        var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
        var value = item[key];

        // update the output
        result[key] = result[key] || [];
        result[key].push(value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

with resulting output:

```
{
    taskList1: [ 'task1 for taskList1', 'task2 for taskList1' ],
    taskList2: [ 'task1 for taskList2', 'task2 for taskList2' ]
}
```

That said, your input data model is also somewhat malformed, with each array element having an unknown key.  You should look at what's actually producing that data and fix that if possible.